# How to do own encryption and decryption on splunk universal forwarder

Tags: java, encryption, splunk

I am trying to do custom encryption and decryption of data on the universal forwarders. I am trying to configure the Splunk UF to use own certificates and forward the encrypted data to the third-party system(Java socket). The reason I am doing this is to recover the Splunk event logs to the java socket connection by decrypting the event changelogs. I tried configuring Splunk UF to use my own certificates for encryption and decryption but it doesn't seem to be working when I tried decrypting the data on Java. Surely I am missing something but could not find the reason.

How can I do this on Splunk UF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splunk uses its own wire format when transmitting data from a univeral forwarder to another forwarder (Splunk2Splunk format, S2S). Even if you are able to decrypt it using the certificates, you will need to decode the packet format, which (to my knowledge) is not public.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
I see, is there any way to get the metadata to the third party system along with event changelogs? I know it is possible in heavy forwarders with a few configuration changes in props.conf and transforms.conf but it would not be applicable in case of Universal forwarder.
Do you know any way to get the metadata at the 3rd party system(non-splunk) from UF?
Many thanks.